# Android Media Recorder not recording long videos on Google Glass

Tags: android, android-camera, google-glass, android-mediarecorder, google-glass-camera

I have written an [opensource camera](https://github.com/krazykira/CuXtomCam) for Google glass but some of the people who have used it have reported that the video recorded doesn't get saved properly for lengthy videos.

I couldn't find info regarding any such limitation in the Android documentation

So Upon checking it out i found that for videos greater than `26 minutes` , the video file got saved in Glass and Its size was around `2.7 GB` but its duration was `0:00`. And it couldn't be played using any video player.

So i am wondering why is that? Why does the video get properly recorded for `duration < 26 minutes` and gets messed up for longer videos.

**Code to start video Recording is**

```
/**
 * Initialize video recorder to record video
 */
private void initRecorder() {
    try {
        File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                + File.separator + Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
                + File.separator + "My Videos");
        if (!dir.exists()) {
            dir.mkdirs();
        }
        videofile = new File(dir, "video.mp4");
        recorder.setCamera(mCamera);

        // Step 2: Set sources
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);
        recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

        // Step 3: Set a CamcorderProfile (requires API Level 8 or higher)
        recorder.setProfile(CamcorderProfile
                .get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH));
        // Step 4: Set output file
        recorder.setOutputFile(videofile.getAbsolutePath());
        // Step 5: Set the preview output
        recorder.setPreviewDisplay(mPreview.getHolder().getSurface());
        // Step 6: Prepare configured MediaRecorder
        recorder.setMaxDuration(3600* 1000);
        recorder.setMaxFileSize(-1);
        recorder.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onError(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
            Log.e("Error Recording", what+" Extra "+extra);

            }
        });
        recorder.setOnInfoListener(new OnInfoListener() {

            @Override
            public void onInfo(MediaRecorder mr, int what, int extra) {
                if (what == MediaRecorder.MEDIA_RECORDER_INFO_MAX_DURATION_REACHED) {
                    endVideoRecording();
                }

            }
        });

        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
        mOverlay.setMode(Mode.RECORDING);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (e != null && e.getMessage() != null)
            Log.e("Error Starting CuXtom Camera for video recording",
                    e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my research it seems that Google glass is only capable of recording video under `2GB` size so if you want to record any video whose size might be greater than that then i would advise you to divide the video into smaller parts and then at the end merge it with [mp4 parser](https://github.com/sannies/mp4parser)

Comment: I can record videos up to 4.1 GB (3.8 GB on Windows) and the native recorder can record even more (it recorded up to 4.7 GB).I don't know how i can record further 4.1 GB.